# Where should pygame be installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-imaging-library

I've installed Pygame and pillow for python 3.6.5 using pip3 on OSX Sierra and I keep getting the same error 'no module named Pygame / pillow'. It did successfully install both modules in the path /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
but can't seem to find them. I have tried moving them into the folder where I store the programs that I write but get strange error messages such as

```
 'from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named base '
```

despite this (from pygame.base import *) not being anywhere in the coding. I have also tried moving them to
usr/local/lib/site-packages but it can't find them there. Does anyone know where python thinks they are stored so I can move them there? Thanks

Comment: pygame should usually be installed in the site-packages directory of the python binary that you want to use it with.  I believe you are using macOS (and should add the tag).  You have at least the system 2.7 and 3.6.5.  A common problem people have is installing packages for one of those (perhaps by mistake) and trying to use them with the other (perhaps by mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Try the command:

```
python -m site
```

Will show you a list of the folders checked for packages by the current python interpreter. But, instead of moving the files there, try to make a clean installation of pygame and do not move the folder.

Append the folder that the installation created to the `PYTHONPATH`, add this line to the `~.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file in the home folder.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/installation/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu maybe this is the same thing. Basically if you did pip3 install with sudo rights then if you run the python3 script with normal rights it will not get the lib and throw this error at you. However if you run the python3 script with sudo it should work.